# Why reference fields are not loaded in Datagrid with react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, react-admin

I have a `Datagrid` in `react-admin`, some of the fields are reference type.
When the `Datagrid` is loaded those fields are not loaded.

It looks like this:
[image]

What is the cause and how can I solve it?
I added the `Resource` for the reference resource.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you add the `<Resource>` for the referenced resource?

Comment: does your API support returning several records from a list of Ids? I suggest you look at the outgoing requests in the Network panel.

Comment: Thank you @FrançoisZaninotto. I think you are right and that is the problem. when looking at the network panel I see in the reference requset under query string parameters `filter: {"id":["60c7a2c8af2c6f3548c2fd48","60c7a304af2c6f3548c2fd49"]}`
 but the response is an empty array. 
Hoe should I support returning several records from a list of Ids? What the url needs to be?

Comment: This really depends on your API. If it supports querying for a list of ids, then check the syntax for that in your API doc, and update your dataProvider to use it. If it doesn't, then change the getMany in the dataProvider to call getOne many times in parallel. And if you can change the API code, add support for getMany!